# Parse text file with powershell, print out lines starting with 2 different strings

Tags: powershell

I have a text file containing repeating patterns of text (a STIG review document)

> ```
> Sample:
> Group ID (Vulid):  V-71989
> Group Title:  SRG-OS-000445-GPOS-00199
> .
> Vulnerability Discussion:  ... 
> Check Content:...
> <hash symbol> some command
> .
> ```

I want to output the line beginning with "Group ID (Vulid)"
AND the line beginning with "#" in the order present in the file.

I have tried:

```
Get-Content C:\in-file.txt | (Where-Object {$_ -match 'Group ID'}) | (Where-Object {$_ -match '#'}) | Set-Content C:\out.txt
```

but it barfs on the "Or".

Comment: The logical OR operator in PowerShell is `-or`, not the `|` character.

Comment: Replacing with "-or" gives me: Where-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'or'.

Answer (score 0):

What [Bill_Stewart is trying to say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796236/parse-text-file-with-powershell-print-out-lines-starting-with-2-different-strin/48796690#comment84595115_48796236) is it should be this:

```
 Get-Content C:\in-file.txt |
    Where-Object {$_ -match 'Group ID' -or $_ -match '#'} |
    Set-Content C:\out.txt
```

Multi-line is just for readability; you can have it as one line in your code.